# Appcelerator Studio - Not Able to launch iOS application

Tags: ios, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I have installed the appcelerator studio latest version `Axway Appcelerator Studio, build: 5.0.0.201712081732` with sdk version `7.0.1.GA`, with node version `v8.9.1` and xCode version `Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)` I am not able to run the application after that, it also doesn't give me any information about the problem below is the screen shot for same -

[image: Appcelerator Error]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what xcode version, and what node version are you running

Comment: usually if you go to "trace" level logging you might get more information regarding the issue

Comment: I have added the Xcode and node version in question. How do I get the trace level logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was an compatibility issue the appcelerator studio Axway `Appcelerator Studio, build: 5.0.0.201712081732` with sdk `version 7.0.1.GA` doesn't work anymore you should have Xcode `Version 9.2 (9C40b)` to be able to successfully build and launch the iOS application.